# C# ToShortDateString

Tags: c#

I wrote this code in vb:

```
expireDate = (DateTime.Parse(decal.DecalExpireDate).ToShortDateString).ToString
```

Now I'm trying to write the same code in c#, this is what I came up with:

```
expireDate = decal.DecalExpireDate.ToString();
expireDate = DateTime.Parse(expireDate).ToShortDateString();
```

Does anybody know how to simplify the c# code so it's one line and two.  It's bugging me that I can do it in one line with vb, but not in c#.

decal.DecalExpireDate is a smallDateTime that I'm retrieving with linq.
expireDate is a string that I'm returning in a function

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why are you calling `ToString()` on a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much exactly how you had it in VB:

```
    expireDate = DateTime.Parse(decal.DecalExpireDate.ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: nice, looks like that's going to work, thougth I tried that, obviously not.  THanks

Answer (score 2):

```
expireDate = DateTime.Parse(decal.DecalExpireDate.ToShortDateString()).ToString();
```

Or, better yet,

```
expireDate = decal.DecalExpireDate.Date.ToString();
```

Comment: it doesn't like those, giving the error system.nullable<System.DateTime> does not contain a definition for 'ToShortDateString'.   I already tried those.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call Parse here, because you are starting with a nullable DateTime (based on your comments).  In fact, you'll get an error message if you try to parse your date when it's null.

This will work as long as the decal expire date is not null:

```
var expireDate = decal.DecalExpireDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

To be safer, though, you should check for null first:

```
var expireDate = decal.DecalExpireDate != null ? decal.DecalExpireDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : null;
```

You can read more about nullable types here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

```
var expireDate = DateTime.Parse(decal.DecalExpireDate).ToShortDateString;
```

Comment: doesn't like that either, maybe it has something to do with the field being nullable?

Answer (score 0):

SmallDateTime should already be returned as a DateTime format ([SQL-CLR Type Mapping (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx)).

It should be as simple as:

```
expireDate = decal.DecalExpireDate.ToShortDateString();
```